# Undefined method stringify keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, haml

I know this question has been asked before and usually it has been related to the update method in the controller. I have been through this already and it does not seem to be where my problem lies. I think mine is related to the view file and the line with the submit tag. I have tried a few things but everything just gives me errors about the wrong number of arguments. Any suggestions would be great!

View:

```
= form_for [:admin, @diagnostic], url: admin_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic), html: {method: :put} do |f|
  .field
    = label_tag :notes
    = f.text_field "notes"
    = submit_tag t('.Save'), @diagnostic.data["Save"]

  .field
    = link_to 'show', admin_diagnostics_path
```

Controller:

```
def update
  @diagnostic = DiagnosticInfo.find(params[:id])
  if @diagnostic.update_attributes(params[:diagnostic_info])
    redirect_to admin_diagnostic_path, notice: 'Successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

Test:

```
it "updates a diagnostic report" do 
  diagnostic_info = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
  diagnostic_info.save!
  visit edit_admin_diagnostic_path(diagnostic_info)
  fill_in 'diagnostic_info_notes',    with: "test notes"
  click_button "Save"
  page.should have_content("Saved")
  page.should have_content("test notes")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is indeed the submit tag.
It should be used like this:

```
submit_tag("display value", html_options)
```

where **html_options** is a hash containing things like:

```
{ class: 'my_class', disabled: true }
```

So change your submit_tag and it will work.
Your view should look like this:

```
= form_for [:admin, @diagnostic], url: admin_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic), html: {method: :put} do |f|
  .field
    = label_tag :notes
    = f.text_field "notes"
    = submit_tag @diagnostic.data["Save"], class: "save"

.field
    = link_to 'show', admin_diagnostics_path
```

**EDIT**:
I think you can even shorten your view as well in Rails now:

```
= form_for [:admin, @diagnostic] do |f|
  .field
    = f.label{ for: :notes }
    = f.text_field "notes"
    = f.submit @diagnostic.data["Save"], class: "save"
  .field
    = link_to 'show', admin_diagnostics_path
```

The reason is, is that the form_for automatically generates the correct path and method if you stick to the standard CRUD operations and naming conventions

**END EDIT**

Not sure what is in your @diagnostic variable, but I guess you want the button to display whatever is in it?